# How to append the radio buttons dynamically into a listview in jquery mobile

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I have tried the following code .But its not showing radio button.Can someone tell me how to do?

```
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  queArr[i] = results.rows.item(i)['question'];
  optaArr[i] = results.rows.item(i)['opta'];
  j += "<li>";
  j += "" + queArr[i] + "";
  j += "<form id=" + i + ">";
  j += "<label>";
  j += "$('<input type="
  radio " name="
  rbtnCount " />') ";
  j += "</label>"
  j += "</form>";
  j += "</li>";
}
$('#list').html(j);
}
```

Comment: Tell jQM to refresh the listview and enhance all child widgets:  $('#list').html(j).listview("refresh").enhanceWithin();